# Rotate element on y-axis to see "behind" background and text on the back

Tags: jquery, css, animation, rotation

I'm using TransformJS to rotate a div `onclick`.  The div rotates 180 degress about its y-axis, thus flipping it over against the window.

My question is this- is there anyway to show separate `background-color` and text on the **back** of the element once you flip it?  Here is a link to a quick jsfiddle i made to test:
http://jsfiddle.net/kSR9H/1/

As you can see from the fiddle, even if you flip the element, the background is still red, and I can't figure out how to place text on the back.

Comment: Make a new element and "flip" it into view when the other goes invisible.

Comment: That is a really creative idea.  I'll see where I can go with that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can split the flip in two parts and after the first, toggle a class that sets a new background..

```
$("p").click(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        rotateY: "+=" + (Math.PI) / 2
    }, 500, function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('flipped'); // toggle class while the flip is in the middle
    }).animate({
        rotateY: "+=" + (Math.PI) / 2
    }, 500);
});
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/kSR9H/2/

- `(Math.PI) / 2` in each animation (*added the /2*)
- callback function in the first half of the rotation that toggles the class
- halved the animation duration to 500ms for each animation for a total of 1 sec (*as the initial*)

Comment: @Hubrid I'll put my upvote in there and it's like the same thing :)